# How to change the underline color of the taskbar (dash-to-panel)

Tags: themes, taskbar

How can I change the orange color of my taskbar (dash-to-panel) icon underline in Ubuntu 20.04? I am already using the gnome-tweaks tool with the Adwaita-dark theme.

[image: taskbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the dock-to-panel extension in which I had to tweak the following settings:
[image]

Set the running indicator style to Metro and then click the settings icon beside it.
[image]

Then you can set the colors you prefer:
[image]

Final result:

[image]